# Who was more powerful? Rama or Hanuman?

Tags: ramayana, rama, hanuman

Hanuman had too much powers in his body and Lord Rama also had many powers and he killed Ravana. But I want to know that who was more powerful? Rama or Hanuman?

Comment: both were avatar's one is Vishnu Avatara and other Shiva

Comment: What kind of question is this? Is this what you got after reading Ramayana? Please grow up.

Comment: Lord Rama was more powerful. But Lord Hanuman was Rudransh.

Answer (score 2):

Hinduism believes each god (not only in hindus but also in christion , muslims) is avatara (part) of bhagavan shrikrishna.

Comparison between two gods on the path of spirituality is called "Namaparadh".

Shriram was avatara of bhagvan vishnu , so undoubtedly Shriram was great , but Lord Hanuman was his bhakta. And in this age we need to learn the Nishkam bhakti like Lord Hanuman that no one does on Supreme god. So Lord Hanuman was also great.

Summary :-

You can not compare the greatness of one god with other. God is one as told in Gita.

Answer (score 2):

Ramakrishna said once that in order to go to Sri Lanka, Rama had to build a bridge. But for Hanuman to cross over all he had to do was take the name of Rama and he flew over the ocean. So the name of Rama is more powerful than both.

Comment: Yes Swamiji. Name **"RAMA"** is more powerful and pious than Sri Rama and everything.

Answer (score 0):

[This sloka about Hanuman](http://www.greenmesg.org/mantras_slokas/bhakta_hanuman-manojavam_marutatulyavegam.php), captures very well, Hanuman's abilities :

> Manojavam Maruthu thulya vegam
>
> Jitendriyam Buddhi mathaam varishtam
>
> Vadhaatmajam Vanara yoodha mukhyam
>
> Sri Rama dhootham Sharanam Prapatye*
>
> To 
>   The one who is as fast as wind and mind,  The one who is a master of
>   senses,  The one is the best among the intelligent,  The son of Vayu,
>   the Lord of Wind,  The one who is a leader of the Vanara,s  The
>   messenger of Lord Rama, To him I offer my obeisances.

The sloka captures many attributes of Hanuman, ironically, much revered in the modern world as well) : 
 1. Speed
 2. Self-Mastery
 3. Intelligence
 4. Lineage
 5. Leadership

However, the last line captures Rama's glory.

What makes Hanuman a great devotee is that, having endowed with all these supreme attributes, he offered these in the service of Lord Rama and became his *messenger*. Ravana had even more knowledge than Rama, but what was the use, his lack of mastery over himself brought his doom.

**Rama** was more powerful, because he could command the love of Hanuman, who had the power of physique and faculty and could re-direct them towards the establishment of Dharma. The ultimate power is the power of Inspiring people with love.